# Want to show rigorously $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Omega}|u(t)|^r = r\langle u_t(t), |u(t)|^{r-2}u(t)\rangle_{H^{-1}(\Omega), H^1(\Omega)}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

We have a bounded domain $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $$u \in L^2((0,T);H^1(\Omega)) \cap H^1((0,T);H^{-1}(\Omega))\cap L^\infty((0,T);L^\infty(\Omega)).$$

I want to show for $r \geq 2$ that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Omega}|u(t)|^r = r\langle u_t(t), |u(t)|^{r-2}u(t)\rangle_{H^{-1}(\Omega), H^1(\Omega)}$$

Note that the RHS is well-defined.

How can I show this properly?

Comment: You should specify the range of $r$ (which I guess is $r\in[2,\infty)$). This should work by approximation. I would recommend writing $|u|^{r-1}\text{sgn}(u)=|u|^{r-2}u$, since the sign function is typically not very well behaved in Sobolev spaces (e.g. $\text{sgn}(u)\notin H^1$).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions... Do you mean approximate $u$ by $u_n$ in a dense subset of $L^2(0,T;H^1) \cap H^2(0,T;H^{-1}) \cap L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty)$ for which the equation does hold? I could not find such a dense subset with the appropriate norm so that I can pass to the limit in the equation. do you have any suggestions on that?

Comment: what about $C_c^{\infty}((0,T)\times\Omega)$?

Comment: can it be true that $C_c^\infty((0,T)\times\Omega)$ is dense in $L^2(H^1)\cap H^1(H^{-1}) \cap L^\infty(L^\infty)$ with the norm combined of those three spaces? In particular I'm not sure about the $L^\infty(L^\infty)$ part. We would need this to pass to the limit in $|u_n(t)|^{r-2}u(t)$ in $L^2(H^1)$.

Comment: @delimit No, $C_c^\infty$ is not dense in $L^\infty(L^\infty)$. But then you can do the approximation with weaker information than that. For instance, it is enough that the approximating sequence $u_m$ (a) converges pointwise, (b) has a uniform bound in $L^\infty(L^\infty)$, (c) has $\nabla u_m$ converging in $L^2(L^2)$, and (d) has $\partial_t u_m$ converging in $L^2(H^{-1})$. Typically approximation by convolution will do that for you.